# How to translate HTML string to real HTML element by ng-for in Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular

As I know, in angular 1.x I can use $sce service to meet my requirment like this

```
myApp.filter('trustAsHTML', ['$sce', function($sce){
  return function(text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  };
}]);
```

and in html file use like this

```
{{ htmlString || trustAsHTML }}
```

Does there has a service like $sce or some pipe or any method can be competent to do that in angularjs 2 version?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In angular2 there's no [`ng-include`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2753), `trustAsHtml`, `ng-bind-html` nor similar, so your best option is to bind to `innerHtml`. Obviously this let you open to all kind of attacks, so it's up to you to parse/escape the content and for that you can use pipes.

```js
@Pipe({name: 'escapeHtml', pure: false})
class EscapeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(value: any, args: any[] = []) {
       // Escape 'value' and return it
   }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    template: `<div [innerHTML]="myHtmlString | escapeHtml"></div>`,
    pipes : [EscapeHtmlPipe]
})
export class Hello {
  constructor() {
    this.myHtmlString = "<b>This is some bold text</b>";
  }
}
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FNBFPE?p=preview) with a naive html escaping/parsing.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Looks like the syntax is now `[innerHTML]`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34424375/86937

Comment: This isn't sufficient for cases where your innerHTML actually contains angular-usable code. In my case, I want to be able to use [routerLink], but I can't.

Comment: @thouliha did you ever figure out a solution to that?

Comment: @Tucker nope. Once you use [innerHTML], you lose all templating abilities. Angular seems to really want you to do all your templating directly in static html.

Comment: the solution in the plnkr is only for <b> tag, how to handle for any(all) html tag?

Answer (score 35):

**Simplest solution:**

```
<div [innerHTML]="some_string"></div>
```

Where `some_string` can be html code, e.g: `some_string = "<b>test</b>"`.

No pipes or anything needed. Supported by Angular 2.0

Comment: How can I have two space-separated properties inside `innerHTML`. Like `prop1_value prop2_value`. Without creating any method to concat them.

Comment: Try doing something like [innerHTML]="{prop1_value + ' ' + prop2_value}"

Comment: It didn't work like this. I added a new `span` and added that prop value there.

Answer (score 4):

I got Same Problem buy I Request the decode HTML from Backend and them you can inject html to your page

```js
// YOUR TS
@Component({
  selector: 'page',
  templateUrl: 'page.html'
})
export class Page {
  inject:any;
  constructor( ) { }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.inject='your HTML code'

  }

}
```

```html
// YOU HTML PAGE

<div [innerHTML]="inject"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution which can be of your help is as below:

```
<p [innerHTML]=your_response_which_is_string></p>
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score -1):

**For property binding use below :**
`<div innerHtml="{{ property }}"></div>`

**For just a string :**
`<div [innerHtml]="<p>property</p>"></div>`