# Ionic v2 bind html

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to bind some text and html data in the view file, but the page doesn't open in some devices.
i tried to surround html with `<div>` tag, but still not working.
I wanted to know is there any alternative of `$sce.trustashtml` in angular2 or in ionic 2.

i have added sample code below

```
<div [innerHTML]="html-variable-from-controller"></div>
```

i tried `[inner-html]` also still no luck

any help will be appreciated

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't open in some devices"? On what devices it works, on what devices it doesn't?

Comment: Don't do this. Why is the server sending you HTML? If you must, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472297/how-to-translate-html-string-to-real-html-element-by-ng-for-in-angular-2.

Comment: its working in samsung and asus zenfone but not in redmi

Comment: @torazaburo sometimes server needs to sends HTML data. For example, Wordpress JSON API returns HTML data for post content.

Answer (score 3):

It happened to my app too. `innerHTML` attribute was trimming audio and iframe elements, in my case.

I got it working by first creating a local variable for that HTML element as follows:

```
<p padding #post_content></p>
```

Here `#post_content` creates a `post_content` local variable.

and then by referencing the particular element using `@ViewChild` Decorator in TypeScript as follows:

```
@ViewChild('post_content') post_content;
```

and assigning the HTML in TypeScript as follows :

```
this.post_content.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.htmlContent;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but in my case the #post_content variable will be inside slidebox and there can be n number of slides with different values.

Comment: @user3660436 can you create a codepen/plunkr of your code?

Answer (score 3):

use ionic tags instead of div, instance:

```
<ion-content [innerHTML]="html-variable-from-controller"></ion-content>
```