# decode a html in typeScript angular 2

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I'm getting from the back-end an encode html but I can't decode it.

I tried with decodeURIComponent and decodeURI.

```html
I got from server='
"&lt;table style=&quot;background-color: white;&quot;&gt;
    &lt;tbody&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
            &lt;td&gt;
                    &lt;div id=&quot;voucher&quot;&gt;
                        &lt;table&gt;
                            &lt;tr&gt;
                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;1&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;ID:&lt;/td&gt;
                                &lt;td colspan=&quot;3&quot; class=&quot;normal-left&quot;&gt;ce203c7c804c4f258947adf3d63b2d7d&lt;/td&gt;
                            &lt;/tr&gt;
                        &lt;/table&gt;
                    &lt;/div&gt;
                &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
    &lt;/tbody&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;"
'
```

```html
// This is my HTML

<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <span [innerHtml]="aux"></span>
  </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

[And this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1byV.jpg)

I used to decode in Jquery with document.getElementById("aux").innerHTML = $('').html(voucher).text();

But I don't know if Angular 2 has something similar.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming this is HTML that you want to insert into the DOM, you should tell the server guys not to escape `<` as `&lt;` etc. Then you can just insert it using `innerHTML`.

Comment: innerHTML is now innerHtml.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you need some directives, such as **[innerHtml]**. Please to use try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39656905/2130322) example:

```
 <div [innerHTML]="var_string"></div>
```

and the `var_string = "<strong>example</strong>";`

Comment: If I use just [innerHTML] as you guys say I'll get "<table><tr></tr></table>". I need to decode first and then I will be enable to use InnerHTML

Comment: Maybe you can use decodeURIComponent.
Like this: var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(var_html_string);

Here is an example -> http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FA0TR4JH7GKL