# render component in ngFor

Tags: angular

I am looping over an object array and inside the object I want to specify a component to load. For example, one of the items in the loop is

```
{
  label: 'Patient\'s Weight',
  subtitle: '',
  component: WeightComponent,
},
```

In the loop I want to render the `WeightComponent`, but it just renders `function WeightComponent()` as text.

I know I am doing this incorrectly, but I am not sure what the correct way is. I also tried

```
{
  label: 'Patient\'s Weight',
  subtitle: '',
  component: '<app-weight></app-weight>',
},
```

but that too just renders as text. Is there a render service type thing I need to use? I seen suggestions to use `[innerHTML]` [How to translate HTML string to real HTML element by ng-for in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472297/how-to-translate-html-string-to-real-html-element-by-ng-for-in-angular-2) but they say that route is open to attacks.

currently doing this which is less than ideal

```
<div *ngFor="let step of selectedDosing.steps; index as i" class="step" [attr.step]="i">
  <ion-label class="step-title">
    <span class="number">{{ i + 1 }}</span>
    <span class="labels">
      <div class="main-label">{{ step.label }}</div>
      <div class="subtitle">{{ step.subtitle }}</div>
    </span>
  </ion-label>
  <app-hepatic-impairment *ngIf="step.component == 'hepatic-impairment'"></app-hepatic-impairment>
  <app-recommended *ngIf="step.component == 'recommended'"></app-recommended>
  <app-weight *ngIf="step.component == 'weight'"></app-weight>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a buil-in [NgComponentOutlet](https://aio-staging.firebaseapp.com/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) directive that will help you with your task.

All you need to do is to add those components to `entryComponents` array of your `NgModule` or `Component` and then simply use it as follows:

**ts**

```
steps: [
  {
    label: 'label',
    component: WeightComponent,
  },
  {
    label: 'label',
    component: RecommendedComponent,
  },
  {
    label: 'label',
    component: WeightComponent,
  },
]
```

**html**

```
<ng-template [ngComponentOutlet]="step.component"></ng-template>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/dAbplZYuQakAvseNV3R9)**

Comment: another question arose. I was calling functions on the component via `@ViewChild(WeightComponent) weightComponent;` using `this.weightComponent.myFunction()` and that seems to have stopped working. I tried replacing it with `WeightComponent.myFunction()` but it says that function does not exist. Do I need to implement some type of onReady thing?